# Processing Media files - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, media, record

I am working on application related to video conference. I have explored about how to record audio and video and tested with UIPickeViewcontroller, here my question is UIPickerViewController will capture audio and video and create any file on it own and store in particular location, However I don't want a file for my application, I need raw data's so that while recording itself I have to transfer that data to other user via server(Don't want to store locally). I have been exploring on AV Foundation, Am I going in right direction? AV foundation will suit for my need? or Where do I need to concentrate?

Any suggestion of yours is greatly appreciated..

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some exploration, I have started using AVAssertwriter to capture frames and process it.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

this is a delegate method use this to capture buffer (sampleBuffer) and process it.